# Is there a trace of users killing a process on windows machine

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, task-manager, event-log

We're debugging a situation in a retail location where the program does a bunch of logging but then everything just stops. it's pretty apparent that the comm to an external web service is taking some time and the user just decides to use the task manager to kill the process rather than wait for the timeout (which is only 25 seconds)(which i understand is forever when you're waiting like that).

I've looked and looked but can't tell definitively: is there a windows event log created somewhere (by default, i hope...) when users terminate processes via the task manager? They're running win server 2008. i'd love to be able to go back and determine how long they let it run before giving up on it.

many thanks.

Comment: I think you can track application crash easily from event but task manager kill can not be that easier to maintain. As tetsujin said restrict the user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if win2k8 has it.. (Win8 and Win2k12 has it for sure), but look for control panel app called "View Reliability History". This control panel applet, is supposed to display any apps which *stopped* working, and to my knowledge and experience, include apps which were explicitly killed by the user.

Do note that this probably won't tell you how long they waited before killing the app. I am not sure if Windows will be able to capture that kind of information on its own.